# How to remove element after unchecking the checkbox from the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={this._handleChartSelection.bind(this, el.graph_id)} /> &nbsp; {el.graph_name}

_handleChartSelection(chartId, checked){
        let data = this.state.selectedChartId
        if(checked)
          data.push(chartId);
        else{
          let i = data.indexOf(chartId);
          data.splice(i,1);
        }
        this.setState({
          selectedChartId: data
        });     
        console.log(this.state.selectedChartId);
        }
```

I am having multi cards with checkboxes on check of that i am pushing into the array, and again if i uncheck also it is pushing into the array.

May i know where i am doing wrong[image: selected chartIDs]

Comment: onClick even you get event object not checked value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are getting the `checked` needs to change

```
_handleChartSelection(chartId, e){
    var checked = e.target.checked;
    let data = this.state.selectedChartId
    if(checked)
      data.push(chartId);
    else{
      let i = data.indexOf(chartId);
      data.splice(i,1);
    }
    this.setState({
      selectedChartId: data
    });     
    console.log(this.state.selectedChartId);
    }
```

Please try this

Comment: _handleChartSelection(chartId, e){},